# Mvc Selectlistitem Binding To DropDownList using Enum

Tags: linq, list, asp.net-mvc-4, enums, selectlistitem

*I Am Trying to bind my enum to dropdownlist using linq*

```
public enum InvoiceTemplateHeader
{
    TENANTNAME,
    TENANTADDRESS,
    TENANTCITY,
    TENANTSTATE,
    TENANTCOUNTRY,
    SONO,
    SODATE,
    SOAMOUNT,
    SOSTATUS,
    EXP_DELDATE,
    INVOICENO,
    INVOICEDATE,
    INVOICEAMOUNT,
    NETAMOUNT,
    HANDLINGCHARGE,
    PAIDAMOUNT,
    INVOCIEQTY,
    TAXPERCENT,
    TAXAMOUNT,
    TAXDETAILVIEW,
    DISCOUNTPERC,
    DISCOUNTAMOUNT,
    BILLINGADDRESS,
    RETAILERNAME,
    RETAILERADDRESS,
    DELIVERYADDRESS,
    TERMANDCONDITIONS,
    SIGINATURE,
    INVOICEDETAIL,
    AMOUNTINWORDS,

    LineItem,
    HeaderData,
    FooterData
}
```

My Method:

```
   private List<SelectListItem> FillInvoiceHeaderTemplate()
        {
            List<String> fields = null;
            fields = _RenderingTextboxFieldsValues.Split(ServiceDataManager.CommaSplitter).ToList();
            return (new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Text = Misc.getResource("APP_CMN_LBL_OptionSelect"), Value = "" } }).Union
                                       (Enum.GetValues(typeof(ServiceDataManager.InvoiceTemplateHeader)).Cast<ServiceDataManager.InvoiceTemplateHeader>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
                                       {
                                           Text = v.ToString(),
                                           Value = v.ToString()

                                       })).ToList();
        }
```

I Am getting All the Enum Values.
I want To filter it out by some values so i hardcoded a string.

```
  private string _RenderingTextboxFieldsValues =
     "TENANTNAME[*],TENANTADDRESS[*],TENANTCITY,TENANTSTATE[*]";
```

i want only these items from enum to be binded.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a `SelectList` that contains only the required values:

```
private List<SelectListItem> FillInvoiceHeaderTemplate()
{
    return new List<SelectListItem>
    {
      new SelectListItem { Text = Misc.getResource("APP_CMN_LBL_OptionSelect"), Value = "" }
      new SelectListItem { Text = InvoiceTemplateHeader.TENANTNAME.ToString(),Value = InvoiceTemplateHeader.TENANTNAME.ToString() },
      new SelectListItem { Text = InvoiceTemplateHeader.TENANTADDRESS.ToString(),Value = InvoiceTemplateHeader.TENANTADDRESS.ToString() },
      new SelectListItem { Text = InvoiceTemplateHeader.TENANTCITY.ToString(),Value = InvoiceTemplateHeader.TENANTCITY.ToString() },
      new SelectListItem { Text = InvoiceTemplateHeader.TENANTSTATE.ToString(),Value = InvoiceTemplateHeader.TENANTSTATE.ToString() }
    }
}
```

But if you still prefer to use linq and filtering you can add a select list item only if it's in `_RenderingTextboxFieldsValues` by adding something like this `.Where(v=> fields.Contains(v.ToString()))` before the `Select`:

```
private string _RenderingTextboxFieldsValues =   "TENANTNAME,TENANTADDRESS,TENANTCITY,TENANTSTATE";

private List<SelectListItem> FillInvoiceHeaderTemplate()
        {
            List<String> fields = null;
            fields = _RenderingTextboxFieldsValues.Split(ServiceDataManager.CommaSplitter).ToList();
            return (new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Text = Misc.getResource("APP_CMN_LBL_OptionSelect"), Value = "" } }).Union
                                       (Enum.GetValues(typeof(ServiceDataManager.InvoiceTemplateHeader)).Cast<ServiceDataManager.InvoiceTemplateHeader>().Where(v=> fields.Contains(v.ToString())).Select(v => new SelectListItem
                                       {
                                           Text = v.ToString(),
                                           Value = v.ToString()

                                       })).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Thank u very much.It Helps

Comment: @TamilmaniP Should mark it as the answer and vote it up, if it worked.